# Find non updated records from list of update statements executing in a batch

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a list of update statements which I am executing them in a batch .I need to find non updated values

Eg : My table has 1 , 2 , 3 records . I am running a execute batch for updating records 3 , 4 . execute batch doesn't throw any error as 4 is not present in DB .

Since update statement doesn't return error , if the key doesn't exist in db , we are not able to find 4 in the above case. please help !!!

Comment: You have to check the number of affected rows.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer . My question is also how will I know number of affected rows.                                                                                                                              If you are saying by update counts we can not                                                         val updateCount = pStmt.executeBatch()...

Comment: I can not, becuase you have not added your code.

Comment: The return value of `executeBatch` is an array with affected rows per execution, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--

Comment: Further to the above comment from @MarkRotteveel see the second example in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26908113/2144390). That answer is for MySQL, but if your Oracle driver supports something similar to `continueBatchOnError` then the approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write select query (may be with group by with the given column id) in your example -

```
select id, count(*) from tab_name group by id
```

Something like this which suits your requirement. Compare these values with update column.

Update query wont give you which records are not updated. However, like mentioned in the comment you will get number of rows effected.